# Two methods with same name but different parameters in POST

Tags: rest, post, cxf

I have two methods with the same name and different parameters as the REST service and type is POST.  It doesn't allow me to have it like this, is there any alternative way that I can achieve the same.

- first method is `getOrders(int a, int b, int c)`
- second method is `getOrders(double a, double b)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "It doesn't allow me to have it" - error message ? Have you set different *paths* for the two methods?

Comment: I want to have the same path with different parameters. Is there a way to achieve the same with one single path.

Comment: The path must be unique.

Comment: Is there no workaround possible.

Comment: Why do you `POST` something and name the method `getOrders`? Of what kind are your parameters?